# Issue creating a ListView menu in Xamarin/Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm having trouble creating a simple menu of links in Xamarin.  The desired layout is an image header, the list of links, and a button at the bottom to close the menu.  I'm using a ListView to display the links.

My layout displays as desired in the Visual Studio Designer, but when run on the emulator or an actual Android device, the ListView takes up the entire screen and the header and footer aren't visible.  I've tried everything I can think of, including several different layouts, and always get the same result.

My XAML is below.  Help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/logo1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/android.r."
    android:background="#ffffffff" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffff8902"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp">
        <Button
            android:text="^"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/menuCloser"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:ems="1"
            android:onClick="OnCloseMenu"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list if you have more items then you have to scroll to get to the bottom to see the footer. Visual studio designer will show you the sample list with less items so that you can see header and footer. If you want footer to be placed in a fixed i.e you don't want to scroll then use relative layout.

Comment: That makes sense, however I would expect the top toolbar and image to show if this were the case, but it doesn't.  I also tried running it with no items added to the ListView at all, and got the same behavior.  The entire screen fills with the ListView, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your listview tag by

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/android.r."
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

1> Issue was in your `android:layout_height="0dp"` it should be `0dp` if you are using weight.

2> My suggestion is to use `RecyclerView` of android as you will face many inconsistency in `ListView`

3> Your code need to be cleanup as i think you are new to android

So as suggestion i just removed some unused properties,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout">
        <Toolbar
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
        </Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/android.r."
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Toolbar
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#ffff8902"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            >
            <Button
                android:text="^"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/menuCloser"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:ems="1"
                android:onClick="OnCloseMenu"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        </Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this did not fix the problem.